# Issue with testing backgroundImage in Vite React TypeScript Jest project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vite, ts-jest

I'm encountering an issue with backgroundImage in my Vite React TypeScript Jest project. When I create a project using create-react-app, everything works as expected. However, when I use Vite, the following code:

```
getByTestId('background').style.backgroundImage
```

returns **url(default)**, instead of the expected value.

I suspect I might be missing some configuration. Is there anyone here who can assist me in resolving this issue? I'm using Vite with React, TypeScript, and Jest.

Please ask if can't reproduce this issue

Comment: Have you tried adding `?url` to the import of the backgroundImage?

Comment: Hi @alextrastero , yes, I tried using the URL instead of importing. In this case, it works as expected. However, not working as excepted on importing the images from assets, I found this issue only occurs in Vite. It works fine in create-react-app.

Comment: @alextrastero can you able to reproduce this?

Comment: not really sorry, I don't have time right now :(

Comment: no issue you can try on your free time✌️